# your iCloud music library session has expired

Tags: itunes, icloud

After deciding I dont want Apple managing any of my music through iCloud I decided to log out of iTunes. Now I am constantly getting an annoying message from iTunes that says:

**your iCloud music library session has expired**

It's very obvious to me that it is expired, as I signed out. How can I get iTunes to stop pestering me with this reminder? I press <kbd>esc</kbd> or CANCEL and it comes back 2 or 3 times before it quits for about 15 minutes then asks me again. I Have to keep hitting CANCEL for it to go away.

Running iTunes 12.2.3.35 on OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may have found an answer. Navigate to iTunes and on the top menu items navigate to the STORE tab. From there sign out of iTunes, and then log in again.

I restarted Itunes just to double check and everything looks good. I haven't been prompted by the annoying message!