# iCloud Music Library and external HDD

Tags: itunes, icloud, macos, external-disk

here's a issue – since I moved my iTunes Library to external HDD, **every time** I launch iTunes it asks Apple ID password.

[image: iTunes – iCloud Music Library auth popup]

When I enter the login/password – all works *almost* perfectly after that, e.g. I can use iTunes Store, download my recent purchases.

“Almost” because except iCloud Music Library:

[image: iCloud Music Library error]

And the same issue repeats if I close and re-open iTunes, it asks Apple ID password again. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: even more interesting – it only affects iTunes. Photos app, for example, works perfectly with iCloud (my photo library is also external hdd).

Comment: Can you try contacting Apple Support at https://getsupport.apple.com and report back what they say?

Comment: When you say you moved your music library to an external HDD--what method did you use to move it? Is iTunes reporting any files (your local copies) as missing?

Comment: @Merlin **this one** – https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204318 Basically copied iTunes folder as described and changed Library in iTunes preferences. Btw, method like this worked fine before with internal ssd. About missing files – yep, some files are missed.

Comment: Hmm... I had a vague theory on that but it doesn't seem likely now. Have you tried signing out (explicitly) of your iTunes Store account and then back in? That seems to have worked for [this user](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/237996/208182).

Comment: @Merlin yes, seems **it works**, thanks. You can write the answer then, and I'll approve it as correct. Btw, by using [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/find-and-sort-the-missing-exclamation-point-tracks-in-1666462567) also restored missed files from iCloud. Solution was simple – smart playlist with missing songs, then delete all, and then missed album/songs will appear in iTunes Library with "cloud" icon, which means they can be re-downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem after moving my iTunes library to my home NAS. Deauthorising and then reauthorising worked for me.